# How to add bearer authorization in the url of webview

Tags: flutter, webview, authorization, bearer-token, webview-flutter

I'm trying to send bearer token to webview URL by using https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter package. I want to add headers with the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onWebViewCreated` to specify a `WebViewController`.

`WebViewController` allow you to specify an url and headers, like this:

```
WebView(
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
      _controller.complete(webViewController);
      webViewController.loadUrl(
        'https://....../my-url',
        headers: {"Bearer": "token"},
      );
  }
  ...
```

In this case, don't use the `initialUrl` param.

And don't forget to initialise `_controller` like this:

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
```